# Is there a way to access quote templates dynamically using APEX?

Tags: apex, community, quote-template

I am working on a project that will require me to auto-populate a pick list field with the current active quote templates. When a new quote template is created, the pick list should be populated with the new quote template name.

Currently I am hardcoding the IDs into custom settings which requires me to grab the ID manually from the quote template editor. Is there a way to access the quote templates through APEX to avoid hardcoding the information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [no](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AczwIAC) direct way to get the quote template Id in Apex. The approach you are following is one of recommended approach.

You can also think of creating [Custom metadata](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=custommetadatatypes_overview.htm) for storing template data. As it is customizable, deployable, packageable, and upgradeable application metadata.

Comment: Hey It looks like You copied the answer from other developer forum.Share the link don't duplicate it.for reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AczwIAC

Comment: Thanks for the reply-- that is currently exactly what I am doing. I have created a custom setting that contains the template name and ID. However, I am trying to avoid hardcoding as I need a dynamic way to access all the available quote template IDs.

Comment: @Pavantej I don't think the answer you quoted is the source for 100% the  answer (and he did link to it). In fact, his suggestion of "Custom Metadata" is a lot better than the suggested on your link.

Comment: Hey @SebastianKessel actually he modified the answer.Before he duplicate it For reference i had provided the link.Now it's fine.

Comment: I have updated the answer and provided link with one more approach. Also included forum link as a reference.

Comment: Thank you for the alternative suggestion! I would prefer using custom metadata over custom settings, however, I still have the problem of storing template data manually. I think I'll have to find another way around this.

Comment: @Pavantej this site doesn't allow you to post just a link as an answer. I don't think he copied it to be dishonest, he just needed to include something besides the link for an answer to not be flagged.